# My unit test project has no connection string - which database is being queried?

Tags: mysql, database, entity-framework, unit-testing, entity-framework-6

I've created a project using Web Api and EF.

I've set up some unit tests which call a few controllers and adds data to the database (through the controllers).

However I fail to see which database the data is being saved to. I initially thought it would be the database for my real project but that is not the case. Come to think of it, I don't even have a connection string in my app.config file.

Which database is being queried? I see the data is persistent through the tests (Test 1 saved a row with Id1, test2 saved a row with Id2 etc.)

On a sidenote I now know I shouldn't be testing the database in my unit tests but I just wanna know which database is being queried here? (remember I got no connection string)

EntityFramework section of app.config:

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

My new app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CH.Tests" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=CH.Tests.mdf;Initial Catalog=CH;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v12.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Cors" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I get the following exception when I run my tests now though:
Test Name:  TestMethod1
Test FullName:  CH.Tests.UnitTest1.TestMethod1
Test Source:    c:\Users\Anders\Dropbox\Projects\Chaser\CH.Tests\UnitTest1.cs : line 23
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:01:28.2206481

Result Message:

> Test method CH.Tests.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 threw exception: 
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50
>   - Local Database Runtime error occurred. The specified LocalDB instance does not exist.

Comment: Is there an `<entityFramework>` section in the unit test project's config file?

Comment: @GertArnold
Yes there is:

    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />

Comment: That's what I though. you're storing data in [local db.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx). The database name will be the namespace + context name.

Comment: Ahh. Well for my other projects I'm using (LocalDb)\v11.0.
I just added a connection string to my app.config but it apparently doesn't use the string. I've updated my question with my complete app.config (including the connection string)